# Lightning Components don't load for Salesforce Platform user license

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, permissions, salesforce1-platform

I have a Lightning Component embedded in a Visualforce page using Lightning Out.

For users with *Salesforce Platform* license the page doesn't load at all. Instead I get following error in JS console:

> https://enxoo-cpq-dev-ed--c.eu6.visual.force.com/c/CPQ_CONF00_OutApp.app?aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT
> 404 (Not Found)

[image]

Changing user license back to *Salesforce* and everything works fine - page loads normally.

I have my domain enabled in the environment.

Is there any magic trick that should be done to enable that?

Comment: I see the same question from another user:

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146182/lightning-component-access-denied

Comment: did you try to open Salesforce Support ticket?

Comment: Do you mind showing your lightning out tag in your vf ?

Comment: Can you recompile all your classes and make sure users with Salesforce Platform profile have access to the Apex Classes related to your Lightning Component.
I've seen LIGHTNING_OUT 404 Error when one of the classes related to the Lightning Component become invalid and required recompilation.

Comment: I did that. All classes compile successfully and users with these licenses have access to all classes / pages both with Permission Set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that one of the `aura:attribute` had `sObject` type declared that was only available for Salesforce license users.

```
<aura:attribute name="contract" type="Contract"/>
```

To solve it you can change it to

```
<aura:attribute name="contract" type="Object"/>
```

But you need to take into account that non-Salesforce license users will not see that object.

Comment: Please accept your answer to resolve this post.